# How to maintain color settings when converting EPS to JPEG with ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, jpeg, eps

I need to convert thousands of EPS files to JPEG, using ImageMagick.

The conversion is almost working - what is different is the colors are more saturated in the converted JPEG than in the original EPS when viewed in a browser.

However when I view the source EPS and the converted JPEG in Photoshop, the colors are identical. Here is the command that is producing the said results:

```
convert -density 300 -quality 100% -colorspace RGB \
        Mbox2.eps -flatten Mbox2.RGB.jpg
```

Does anybody know what's causing this and how to fix it?

Answer (score 4):

Most likely, Photoshop is using sRGB (or mayby, CYMK). So you should try:

```
convert Mbox2.eps \
    -density 300 -quality 100% -colorspace sRGB -flatten Mbox2.sRGB.jpg

convert Mbox2.eps \
    -density 300 -quality 100% -colorspace CMYK -flatten Mbox2.CMYK.jpg
```

and see if one of your results now is more like you expect it to be.